# ScrollView with GradientColor

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, xcode8, ios10

I am trying to make scroll view with gradient background color, but it shows me gradient color only and could not see scroll view! No error waning.

```
    mainScrollView.frame = view.frame
    imageArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "business-improvement"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_3601"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_4261"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "IMG_4264")]


    for i in 0..<imageArray.count{

        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.image = imageArray[i]
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(i)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: xPosition, y:0, width: self.mainScrollView.frame.width, height: self.mainScrollView.frame.height)

        let mainScrollView = CAGradientLayer()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.01, green:0.34, blue: 0.38, alpha: 1.0)
        mainScrollView.frame = self.view.bounds
        let color1 = UIColor(red: 0.11, green:0.04, blue: 0.32, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let color2 = UIColor(red: 0.0, green:0.18, blue: 0.20, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        mainScrollView.colors = [color1, color2]
        mainScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 690)
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(mainScrollView)
```

Answer (score 0):

I try the same and this works for me :

```
 self.MyItem.applyGradient_2(colours: [UIColor(red:0.09, green:0.91, blue:0.65, alpha:1.0), UIColor(red:0.08, green:0.92, blue:0.43, alpha:1.0)])

extension UIView {
    func applyGradient_2(colours: [UIColor]) -> Void {
        self.applyGradient_(colours: colours, locations: nil)
    }

    func applyGradient_(colours: [UIColor], locations: [NSNumber]?) -> Void {
        let gradient: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.frame = self.bounds
        gradient.colors = colours.map { $0.cgColor }
        gradient.locations = locations
        self.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    }
}
```